# Django, DRF: To remove a specific field of the serializer only on the first page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I remove `field3` and `field4` only on the first page?
I need something that can be dynamically reused as I plan to use it in multiple views.

How can I dynamically delete `field3` and `field4` without creating multiple serializers?

```py
class CustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('field', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4')


class CustomSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('field5', 'field6', 'field3', 'field4')


class CustomSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('field7', 'field8', 'field3', 'field4')


class CustomView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CustomSerializer

class CustomView2(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CustomSerializer2

class CustomView3(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CustomSerializer3
```

Comment: I don't get it why you mention them at the first place when later you remove them ? What is the purpose of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using serializer context. This way you can assess request data and params in you serializer methods such as `to_representation` which is useful in your case.
PS. This code was written in stackoverflow window, it may include some mistakes, but it shows an approach

```
class CustomView(ListAPIView):
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs['context'] = {'request': self.request}
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

class CustomSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']
    
    def to_representation(self, instance, **kwargs):
        if self.context.get('request').query_params.get('page') == 1:
            return {'field1': instance.field1, 'field2': instance.field2}
        return {'field1': instance.field1, 'field3': instance.field3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write two different serializers the first one with `field3` & `field4` and other one does not include these two fields. Then from your views use `get_serializer_class()` method to select the appropriate serializer for the provided `page`.

You will need some thing like this in your views -

```
class CustomSerializerWithFields(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('field', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4')

class CustomSerializerWithoutFields(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('field', 'field2')

class CustomView(ListAPIView):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.query_params["page"]==1:
            return CustomSerialierWithoutFields
        return CustomSerializerWithFields
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation. I would like to come up with a way to do that, but if I want to use it with multiple views & serializers, I have to create serializers for them, so I need to dynamically remove certain fields from the serializer.

Comment: The proposed solution won't need multiple views just 2 serializers. Anyways, I am not aware of how to remove fields dynamically for the page 1.

Comment: I need to remove it dynamically in one serializer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing them from queryset and the dropping the null fields from the serializer using to_representation

```
    class CustomSerializer
        class Meta:
            model = Model
            fields = '__all__'
          
        def to_representation(self, instance):
            rep = super().to_representation(instance)
            return {k: v for k, v in rep.items() if v is not None}
```